# Jenkins - Git SCM plugin not working when checking out in K8S container slave

Tags: java, git, kubernetes, jenkins, groovy

I am using Kubernetes plugin and using my own image.
This image has git and worked before when I was using ec2 slaves.

From some reason, after moving to container using K8s plugin I'm getting this issue after using GitSCM checkout plugin.

But when I use "sh git clone..." it works perfectly.

what am I missing?  JENKINS-30600? Permission denied?

How could it be?

```
Warning: JENKINS-30600: special launcher org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pipeline.ContainerExecDecorator$1@6c6a5bef; decorates RemoteLauncher[hudson.remoting.Channel@124fe7dc:JNLP4-connect connection from ip-10-20-119-149.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.20.119.149:53594] will be ignored (a typical symptom is the Git executable not being run inside a designated container)
15:02:29  Cloning the remote Git repository
15:02:29  ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
15:02:29  hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/PR__test_container_main/infra-kit
15:02:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1049)
15:02:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:802)
15:02:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:158)
15:02:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:151)
15:02:29    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
15:02:29    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
15:02:29    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
15:02:29    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
15:02:29    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
15:02:29    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
15:02:29    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
15:02:29    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:125)
15:02:29    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
15:02:29    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from ip-10-20-119-149.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.20.119.149:53594
15:02:29        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1784)
15:02:29        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
15:02:29        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1000)
15:02:29        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:143)
15:02:29        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor745.invoke(Unknown Source)
15:02:29        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
15:02:29        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
15:02:29        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:129)
15:02:29        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.execute(Unknown Source)
15:02:29        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1226)
15:02:29        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1309)
15:02:29        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:129)
15:02:29        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:97)
15:02:29        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:84)
15:02:29        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
15:02:29        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
15:02:29        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
15:02:29        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
15:02:29        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
15:02:29        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
15:02:29  Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "/usr/bin/git init /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/test_container_main/infra-kit" returned status code 1:
15:02:29  stdout: 
15:02:29  stderr: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/test_container_main/infra-kit/.git: Permission denied
15:02:29  
15:02:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2734)
15:02:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2660)
15:02:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2656)
15:02:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1981)
15:02:29    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1047)
15:02:29    ... 12 more
```